# Quickbooks - How to export a list of invoices with the corresponding customer name?

Tags: quickbooks

I am looking to have an excel file with two columns.  Column one would be a list of all invoice numbers.  Column two would be the name under the corresponding invoice number.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I'm using QuickBooks Pro 2012.

Reports > Custom Reports > Transactions Detail (or, Summary Detail if you are looking for a summary report) > Then you can choose the columns and use filters to weed out the stuff you don't want.